# Selecting dates in Pandas DataFrame to calculate daylight savings time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to select a range of dates in a Pandas DataFrame (containing half hourly data) to determine the daylight savings time of those days. The start of DST is the last Sunday of September, and it ends on the first Sunday of April.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

...

df0 = df0.set_index('datetime')

df0['mnth'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df0.index).month
df0['dow'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df0.index).dayofweek # Mon=0, ..., Sun=6

start_dst = df0.iloc[(df0.mnth==9) & (df0.dow==6).idxmax()]
end_dst = df0.iloc[(df0.mnth==4) & (df0.dow==6).idxmin()]
df0.index[start_dst:end_dst] = df0.index + pd.Timedelta('1h')
```

My data is essentially shifted 1 hour backwards in the Sep-Apr period, so I need to add 1h to the timestamps in this period. But when I define `start_dst`, I get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'and_' with a dtyped [bool] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

I'm not sure how to change `start_dst`.

**Edit:** Here is a sample dataframe:

```
# End DST: first Sunday of April, 1h backward (5 Apr 2020)
# Start DST: last Sunday of September, 1h forward (27 Sep 2020)
# 4,5,6 April 2020, 26,27,28 Sep 2020
d1 = '2020-04-04'
d2 = '2020-04-05'
d3 = '2020-04-06'
d4 = '2020-09-26'
d5 = '2020-09-27'
d6 = '2020-09-28'

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime([d1]*24, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df1['time'] = (pd.date_range(d1, periods=24, freq='H') - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)).time
df1 = df1.set_index('date')

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime([d2]*25, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df2['time'] = (pd.date_range(d2, periods=25, freq='H') - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)).time
df2 = df2.set_index('date')

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3['date'] = pd.to_datetime([d3]*24, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df3['time'] = (pd.date_range(d3, periods=24, freq='H')).time
df3 = df3.set_index('date')

df4 = pd.DataFrame()
df4['date'] = pd.to_datetime([d4]*24, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df4['time'] = (pd.date_range(d4, periods=24, freq='H')).time
df4 = df4.set_index('date')

df5 = pd.DataFrame()
df5['date'] = pd.to_datetime([d5]*23, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df5a = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('00:00', '01:59', freq='H').time)
df5b = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('01:00', '01:59', freq='H').time)
df5c = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('03:00', '22:00', freq='H').time)
df5['time'] = pd.concat([df5a,df5b,df5c],axis=0).values
df5 = df5.set_index('date')

df6 = pd.DataFrame()
df6['date'] = pd.to_datetime([d6]*24, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df6['time'] = (pd.date_range(d6, periods=24, freq='H') - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)).time
df6 = df6.set_index('date')

df0 = pd.DataFrame()
z = df1.append(df2).append(df3).append(df4).append(df5).append(df6)
df0['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(z.index.astype(str)+' '+z.time.astype(str),
                            format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df0 = df0.set_index('datetime')

df0['mnth'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df0.index).month
df0['dow'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df0.index).dayofweek # Mon=0, ..., Sun=6
df0['hour'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df0.index).hour
```

Comment: If possible can you pls provide a  sample dataframe?

Comment: @Anurag Dabas I have added more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create/define a function that will give you the index by calculating the condition:

```
def get_indexex():
    try:
        idxmx=df0.index==((df0['dow']==6).idxmax())
        idxmn=df0.index==((df0['dow']==6).idxmin())
        start_dst = df0.loc[(df0['mnth']==9) & idxmx]
        end_dst = df0.loc[(df0['mnth']==4) & idxmn]
        if not start_dst.index.tolist():
            return df0.loc[:end_dst.index[-1]].index
        elif not end_dst.index.tolist():
            return  df0.loc[start_dst.index[0]:].index
        else:
            return  df0.loc[start_dst.index[0]:end_dst.index[-1]].index
    except IndexError:
        start_dst=df0.loc[(df0['dow'].eq(6) & df0['mnth'].eq(9)) & df0['hour'].eq(2)]
        end_dst=df0.loc[df0['mnth'].eq(4) & df0['hour'].eq(3)]
        if not start_dst.index.tolist():
            return df0.loc[:end_dst.index[-1]].index
        elif not end_dst.index.tolist():
            return  df0.loc[start_dst.index[0]:].index
        else:
            return  df0.loc[start_dst.index[0]:end_dst.index[-1]].index
```

Finally:

```
df0['dt']=df0.index
m=df0.index.isin(get_indexex())
df0.loc[m,'dt']=df0.loc[m,'dt']+pd.Timedelta('1H')
df0.index=df0.pop('dt')
```

**Reasons to some things:**

- you can't make change in the index of subset so for this we created `'dt'` column and set that value equal to the `index` of our dataframe
- we make idxmx variable for `idxmax()` and idxmn variable for `idxmin()` which are comparing values of `idxmax()` and `idxmin()` with the `index` of dataframe and siving you a bolean array and you are getting error because `(df0.dow==6).idxmax() or (df0.dow==6).idxmin()` gives you a single value not a Series of boolean value
- we are defining a function named `get_indexex()` which will give you the indexes of index where condition satisfies to handle such situation when `start_dst` is an empty dataframe
- Also 1 thing to notice here inside the function we are gettting the index upto 0th index of start_dst and last index of end_dst for those cases if start_dst and end_dst contains multiple entries

**Update:**

You are getting `2020-04-05 23:00:00` from the function because your condition satisfying so any one of the end_dst and start_dst giving you the result so if you don't want then you an remove this case from the function so now it becomes:

```
def get_indexex():
    start_dst=df0.loc[(df0['dow'].eq(6) & df0['mnth'].eq(9)) & df0['hour'].eq(2)]
    end_dst=df0.loc[df0['mnth'].eq(4) & df0['hour'].eq(3)]
    if not start_dst.index.tolist():
        return df0.loc[:end_dst.index[-1]].index
    elif not end_dst.index.tolist():
        return  df0.loc[start_dst.index[0]:].index
    else:
        return  df0.loc[start_dst.index[0]:end_dst.index[-1]].index
```

Finally:

```
df0['dt']=df0.index
m=df0.index.isin(get_indexex())
df0.loc[m,'dt']=df0.loc[m,'dt']+pd.Timedelta('1H')
df0.index=df0.pop('dt')
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I was wondering if it's possible to be more specific about the start/end dates. If I want `start_dst` and `end_dst` to also define a time, I can write `start_dst = df.loc[(df.mnth==9) & idxmx & (df.hour==2)]; end_dst = df.loc[(df.mnth==4) & idxmn & (df.hour==3)]` but then I get an error `IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` which refers to the `get_indexex()` function.

Comment: The start of DST is the last Sunday of September (move clock forward 1 hour at 2am). It ends on the first Sunday of April (move clock back 1 hour at 3am)

Comment: @MedullaOblongata you are getting this error because both start_dst and end_dst returning empty dataframe with hour condition so what you wanted to do in this case?

Comment: I was think of defining `start_dst` as the last Sunday (`dow=6`) of September (`mnth==9`) at 2am (`hour==2`) and `end_dst` as the first Sunday of April(`mnth==4`) at 3am (`hour==3`)

Comment: @MedullaOblongata updated answer...kindly have a look and sir pls let me know if it is working for you or not..If it is working then I will explain the function **:)**

Comment: @MedullaOblongata but sir for now in function we are checking your previous condition if they don't return dataframe then we are checking your new condition

Comment: Thanks :), it seems to work ... the first entry of `df0` is `2020-04-05 00:00:00, hour=23` and but should it be `2020-04-05 00:00:00, hour=23`?? The second entry is `2020-04-04 00:00:00, hour=0`. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: @MedullaOblongata yes sir....updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is because of the idxmax() and idxmin(); Both return the index number, and this index isn't a bool type. The (df0.mnth==9) and (df0.mnth==4) will return a array of True and False; and when u try compare them, this error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

The thought of dealing manually with DST gives me headache. Pandas timestamp objects (single values of a Series) have the `dst()` function, which returns the daylight saving time difference.